dynamic task mapping with using SimpleHttpOperator(uri change dynamlically)
I'm trying to make dynamic uri using dynamic task mapping
DAG's flow is  fetch_types >> request_tasks(dynamic task mapping)
fetch_types task is using postgresql operator to get types from database.
I've tried to make dynamic task but it returns error.
what i've tried to make dynamic task is below

request_tasks = SimpleHttpOperator.partial(
        task_id='request_sync_task',
        http_conn_id='http_conn',
        endpoint='/api/v1/{{ type }}',
        method='GET',
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        response_check=lambda response: response.status_code == 200,
        dag=dag,
    ).expand(
        type="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='fetch_types', key='return_value') | map(attribute='1') }}"
    )

However, this approach returns SimpleHttpOperator.expand() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'.
I'm not sure how to set up the uri path to actually use type values.

Indeed SimpleHttpOperator has no argument call 'type'. Try to use 'endpoint' instead - removing it from the partial and into the exapnd.
